# Vuejs how to pass data as a prop to a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I build following component:

```
var Modal = Vue.component('modal', {

    template: `
        <div id="modal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p>{{ link }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,

    props: [
        'link'
    ],

});
```

And I would like to change the link data dynamically after I sent successfully an axios post.

My vue instance

```
new Vue({

    el: '#form',

    components: {
        'modal': Modal
    },

    data: {
        userId: '',
        title: '',
        body: '',
        snippetLink: '',
    },

    methods: {

        publish (e) {
            var self = this;
            axios.post('/snippets',  {
                title: this.title,
                body: this.content,
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("success");
                self.link = response.data.hash; // Here I tried to add the reponse content to the vue component's p
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
        },
```

My Html Markup:

```
        <modal link=""></modal>
       ...
        <button type="button"                      
                   v-bind:class="{ 'modal-trigger': !isActiveModal }"
                   @click="publish">Publish
                   <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
```

So I am sending an axios post to my server successfully and get the data, I would like to open a modal window and put the data in a p tag, so far the modal pops up after my post but I am not sure my it does not change the content of the p tag.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding , Snippetlink property can be used to hold data from server.

```
self.Snippetlink = response.data.hash;
```

and Pass Snippetlink to link attribute of the snippet-model

```
 <snippet-modal :link="Snippetlink"></snippet-modal>
```

Comment: hmm it should returns "SnippetLink", not the response

Comment: @rupesh_padhye I am going to accept it but could you add for information of what excatly is happening ...

Answer (score 0):

rupesh_padhye's answer is correct. This is just a further explanation.

First of all, to store the response data to a Vue component, you need to define a key in `data` for that purpose first. So to make this line work: `self.link = response.data.hash;`, you need to add `link` as a key for the Vue component's data:

```
data: {
        userId: '',
        title: '',
        body: '',
        snippetLink: '',
        link: ''
    },
```

If you mean `snippetLink`, change the line to `self.snippetLink = response.data.hash;`

Secondly, to pass the data as a prop to a child component, you have to specify the prop name, as well as the data key being passed. For instance, to pass your component's `link` as a prop with the same name to the `snippet-modal` component, you need: `<snippet-modal :link="link"></snippet-modal>`